# _UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_ssock

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, mavlink

I am running an async method inside an interval schedule method and sending data to websocket after every second. It works fine for a while but after sometime below error appear in celery worker terminal. I using python 3.8.5 and djnago 3.1.7. Can anyone help me resolving this issue.

[image]

```
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,033: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] 24
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,033: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] Exception ignored in:
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,033: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x7eff8a9e8700>
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 656, in __del__
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 58, in close
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 92, in close
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 99, in _close_self_pipe
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] AttributeError
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] :
[2021-06-25 17:54:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_ssock'
```

Comment: I have the same issue with [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/), I don't know what is the problem.